# I would like to only output the message part of this debugging's output instead of all the code and id's

Tags: java, exception

I am looking to only recieve the message= part of the following code, after the comma:

```
PostJSONImpl{
    id='1381405208752125_1846149835610991', 
    from=CategoryJSONImpl [id=636802996442414, name=Jasmine Jenise Johnson, category=null, createdTime=null], 
    to=[IdNameEntityJSONImpl [name=Cairo Swappers and Shoppers, id=1381405208752125]], 
    message='White IPhone 4S Verizon Wireless perfect condition no scratches or cracks can be used on page plus
```

Comment: get this line from this string   'White IPhone 4S Verizon Wireless perfect condition no scratches or cracks can be used on page plus

Comment: "Give me the code" questions are not well received here, you should read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) part from the help section.

Comment: @Pshemo this looks more like a string representation of some object

Comment: @RC. You are right. I didn't check if it was valid JSON. Comment removed.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get just the message from java's

```
e.getMessage()
```

Fuction. You can though look in the JSON Parser.